# Transiting through the Schengen Area with an expired American Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen, transit, transit-visas, schengen-visas

I am an American citizen currently doing a summer internship in Italy. I arrived on May 13. My parents will be coming at the end of my 90 days to go on a Euro trip together. On August 10th (the end of my 90 day period), I plan to exit the Schengen area for a Non-Schengen country with my boyfriend to go on  vacation together, probably Albania. However, looking at the plane tickets back to the United States I noticed most of them have layovers in Schengen Member State airports like Cologne. I was wondering what the rules were for transiting (1/2 hour layover without leaving the airport) like this? Would I need to get an Airport Transit Visa? I have been extremely careful to leave the Schengen Area when my time is over, so I am interested in any advice or information that could be provided. 
Thank you

Comment: Do you actually have a visa sticker in your passport? If so, it should be a type D visa, in which case you don't count days spent entirely in Italy toward the 90/180 rule.  If not, you do not have a visa, and the title of your question is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

No as a citizen of the united states (or anyone holding  valid U.S. visa) you do not require a transit visa. This is only where you do not need to leave the airport and pass through immigration (eg transferring between different airports) or where you would have a second schengen layover - again requiring you to enter the schengen zone - even if you remain airside the whole time. 
[schengenvisainfo](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/transit-schengen-visa/)

[European Commision Visa policy](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa/docs/visa_lists_en.pdf)  - second source

Comment: This is correct, but you should warn the traveler not to book an itinerary with two stops in the Schengen area (e.g., Tirana-Munich-Frankfurt-Newark), because such an itinerary requires passing through passport control.  Also, schengenvisainfo is an unofficial site. It has proven itself to be unreliable.

Comment: @phoog - that is a valid point, I will update the answer accordingly